# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Slide in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Does anyone know how I can get a Twitter Bootstrap modal to smoothly slide in from the top of the browser window into position rather than fade in quickly?

I have been looking at [this link](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php) but can't seem to see how to achieve a slide-in trasition rather than a fade.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

I have the following CSS at the moment:

```
.modal-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.modal {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 560px;
    z-index: 1050;
}
.modal.fade {
    top: -25%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0s, top 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.modal.fade.in {
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: If your element already have the class `.fade`, then make sure you don't append it to DOM at the same time you initialize bootstrap (use `setTimeout` to defer bootstrap on the next tick).

Comment: Thanks Simon, this makes sense I will make sure that's not setup :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem the w3resource example was the "in" class added to the #example div. If you **remove the "in" class** it should work the way you expect an slide in from the top...

```
<div class="container">  
  <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
  <div id="example" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; ">  
  <div class="modal-header">  
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
  <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
  </div>  
  <div class="modal-body">  
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
  <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
  </div>  
  <div class="modal-footer">  
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
  </div>  
  </div>  
  <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
</div>
```

**Working on Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/60158

Comment: Awesome thanks Skelly! I also didn't even know Bootply existed so thanks for sharing this as well :)